# Visual Studio 2015 Add Plugin - Unable to parse plugin.xml - android namespaces

Tags: android, visual-studio-cordova

I have seen several variations on this question, some suggesting that plugin.xml is invalid.

Last week I was using VS 2015 Enterprise in trial mode. I uninstalled that and installed VS 2015 Professional and now I am unable to add the same plugin to a new project.

In this case it seems that the plugin is invalid:
https://github.com/michael79bxl/cordova-barcode-scanner-plugin2/blob/master/plugin.xml

When I attempting to load the XML myself I get this error:

```
'android' is an undeclared prefix. Line 78, position 17.
```

It seems like something is broken in my Visual Studio setup. I believe I have added everything necessary for Android development, but the error won't go away.